# Show battery percentage in Lubuntu's LXPanel

Tags: indicator, battery

How can I show the battery percentage in Lubuntu's LXPanel? I have xfce4-power-manager icon but it doesn't have the "show percentage" option.

Answer (score 0):

The indicator **Battery Status** should be what you are looking for:

**1.** Add the repository

`ppa:iaz/battery-status`

**2.** Install the package

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install battery-status`

**3.** And last, run **Battery Status** as an indicator applet

`/usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator`